# Removing template part when not on homepage if / else

Tags: pagination, homepage, conditional-tags

Thank you in advance for any help!
What I am trying to do is remove a template part from my home page after the user clicks on the pagination links from the posts, right now my template part serves as a "hero" or "featured" area, and I would like it to go away when the user looks at older posts, eg the pagination, here is what I am doing so far and it is not working, thanks!

```
<?php if( is_home() || is_front_page() ) : ?>
 <?php get_template_part( 'hero' ); ?>
<?php else : ?>
 <?php get_template_part( 'blank' ); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

as you can see i created a blank template , not sure if this was necessary , does it need to be inside the loop? thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you need is [`is_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_paged).

```
if (is_paged()) {
  // page 2 or later of an archive
} else {
  // only the first page of an archive
}
```

With your code, I think but am not 100% sure, that you want:

```
if( !is_paged() && ( is_home() || is_front_page() ) ) :
 get_template_part( 'hero' );
else :
 get_template_part( 'blank' );
endif;
```